# How useful is C's "true" sizing of variables?

Tags: programming-languages, c, language-design

One thing that always intuitively struck me as a positive feature of C (well, actually of its implementations like gcc, clang, ...) is the fact that it does not store any hidden information next to your own variables at runtime. By this I mean that if you for example wanted a variable "x" of the type "uint16_t", you could be sure that "x" will only occupy 2 bytes of space (and won't carry any hidden information like its type etc.). Similarly, if you wanted an array of 100 integers, you could be sure it is as big as 100 integers.

However, the more I am trying to come up with concrete use cases for this feature the more I am wondering if it actually has *any* practical advantages at all. The only thing I could come up with so far is that it *obviously* needs less RAM. For limited environments, like AVR chips etc., this is definitely a huge plus, but for everyday desktop / server use cases, it seems to be rather irrelevant. Another possibility I am thinking of is that it *might* be helpful / crucial for accessing hardware, or maybe mapping memory regions (for example for VGA output and the like) ... ?

My question: Are there any concrete domains that either can't or can only very cumbersomely be implemented without this feature?

P.S. Please tell me if you have a better name for it! ;)

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I think I understand what your problem is. It's because there could be multiple answers, right? Well, I get that this question might not suit the way stackexchange works, but I honestly don't know where to ask elsewise ...

Comment: I believe the technical term for this is simply "static typing without any RTTI (run-time type information)". It's worth noting that [at least some C++ compilers let you disable RTTI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486609/when-can-compiling-c-without-rtti-cause-problems), so it's not unique to C, though C might be the only still-popular non-assembly language where exactly zero RTTI remains the "default" implementation.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat Okay, that sucks ... Oh well, maybe i'll try asking this on a more relaxed forum ...

Comment: @lxrec RTTI is stored in the vtable, and objects only store a pointer to the vtable. Additionally, types only have RTTI if they already have a vtable because they have a `virtual` member function. So RTTI never increases the size of any objects, it only makes the binary larger by a constant.

Comment: @delnan Yes, but that still means that every object pointer has to carry a pointer to its vtable. It might by far not be as big as the full vtable, but it's still 4-8 bytes ...

Comment: @ThomasOltmann Every object *that has virtual methods* needs a vtable pointer. You can't have the functionality virtual methods without that. Moreover, you explicitly opt into having virtual methods (and hence, a vtable).

Comment: Yes okay, that makes sense. However, I am not sure if most compilers actually distinguish between pointers to objects with virtual methods and pointers to primitives / non-vtable objects ...

Comment: @ThomasOltmann You seem very confused. It's not a pointer to an object that carries a vtable pointer, it's the object itself. I.e., `T *` is always the same size and the `T` may contain a hidden field that points to the vtable. And **no C++ compiler ever** inserted vtables into objects that don't need them.

Comment: @delnan Okay, got it now.

Comment: System memory isn't the only factor, consider CPU cache too. (and the performance loss from cache misses).

Comment: @lxrec: the OP is asking about C (not C++), so mentioning C++ is off-topic

Comment: Basically you ask what are cons of RTTI.

Comment: "if you for example wanted a variable "x" of the type "uint16_t", you could be sure that "x" will only occupy 2 bytes of space" – Is that true? I must admit that I don't know much about C, but there are at least two hidden assumptions in there, that seem questionable to me. 1) That an `uint16_t` occupies exactly 16 bits, and 2) that a `byte` is exactly 8 bits. Regarding 1), I vaguely recall that the spec says that an `uint16_t` is 16 bits "wide", but it has a very specific definition of "wide" that allows for padding, which means that an `uint16_t` could take up more than 16 bits. …

Comment: … regarding 2), the spec only guarantees that a `byte` is at least as wide as a `char`, and that a `char` can hold at least 255 distinct values. So, all the spec guarantees is that a `byte` is wider than 7 bits.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that this is the right question to ask. You wouldn't store additional data just for the heck of it. Any language that does keep track of auxiliary data does so for a purpose, because the data is *required* to provide some higher-level feature. C does not provide any such feature because it is designed to be a low-level language.

Comment: A common learning example in C is creating a variable type which 'knows' its type (using a struct and/or union). Notice that when you do this, it is the programmer which has the responsibility to do this, to add the extra storage, to check the extra bits to see what type it is, etc. If you were designing the C runtime, you could well ask the question "what's the point of doing this kind of runtime type introspection if the programmer can do it himself if needed?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several benefits, the obvious one is at compile time to ensure that things like function parameters match the values being passed in.

But I think you are asking about what is happening at runtime.

Keep in mind that the compiler will create a runtime that embeds knowledge of the data types in the operations it performs. Each chunk of data in memory may not be self describing, but the code inherently knows what that data is (if you have done your job correctly).

At runtime things are a bit different than you think.

For example, don't assume that only two bytes are used when you declare uint16_t.
Depending on the processor and word alignment it can occupy 16, 32 or 64 bits on the stack. You may find that your array of shorts consumes much more memory than you expected.

This can be problematic in certain situations where you need to reference data at specific offsets. This happens when communicating between two systems that have different processor architectures, either via a wireless link, or via files.

C allows you to specify structs with bit level granularity:

```c
struct myMessage {
  uint8_t   first_bit: 1;
  uint8_t   second_bit: 1;
  uint8_t   padding:6;
  uint16_t  somethingUseful;
}
```

This structure is three byte long, with a short defined to start at an odd offset. It will also need to be packed in order to be exactly as you defined it. Otherwise the compiler will word-align the members.

The compiler will generate code behind the scenes to extract this data and copy into a register so you can do useful things with it.

Now you can see that every time my program accesses a member of the myMessage struct, it will know how exactly how to extract it and operate on it.

This can become problematic and hard to manage when communicating between different systems with different versions of software. You must carefully design the system & code to ensure both sides have exactly the same definition of the data types. This can be quite challenging in some environments. This is where you need a better protocol that contains self describing data such as Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).

Lastly, you make a good point to ask how important this is in the desktop/server environment. It really depends on how much memory you are planning to use. If you are doing something like image processing, you may end up using a large amount of memory which may affect the performance of your application.
This is definitely always a concern in the embedded environment where memory is restricted and there is no virtual memory.

Comment: "You may find that your array of shorts consumes much more memory than you expected." This is wrong in C: Arrays are guaranteed to contain their elements in a gap-free fashion. Yes, the array needs to be aligned properly, as does a single `short`. But this is a one-time requirement for the start of the array, the rest is automatically aligned correctly by virtue of being consecutive.

Comment: Also, the syntax for the padding is wrong, it should be `uint8_t padding: 6;`, just like the first two bits. Or, more clearly, just the comment `//6 bits of padding inserted by the compiler`. The structure, as you have written it, has a size of at least nine bytes, not three.

Answer (score 9):

You hit on one of the only reasons this is useful: mapping external data structures.  Those include memory-mapped video buffers, hardware registers, *etc.*  They also include data transmitted intact outside the program, like SSL certificates, IP packets, JPEG images, and pretty much any other data structure that has a persistent life outside the program.

Answer (score 5):

C is a low-level language, nearly a portable assembler, so its data structures and language constructs are close to the metal (data structures have no hidden costs - except [padding, alignment and size constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) imposed by hardware and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)). So C indeed does not have dynamic typing natively. But if you need it, you could adopt a *convention* that all your values are aggregates starting with some type information (e.g. some `enum` ...); use `union`-s and (for array-like things) [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in `struct` containing also the size of the array.

<sup>(when programming in C, it is your responsibility to define, document, and follow useful conventions - notably pre- and post- conditions and invariants; also [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) requires expliciting conventions about who should `free` some heap-`malloc`ated memory zone)</sup>

So, to represent values which are boxed integers, or strings, or some kind of [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29)-like [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28programming%29), or vectors of values, you'll conceptually use a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (implemented as a union of pointers) -always starting by the type kind-, e.g.:

```
enum value_kind_en {V_NONE, V_INT, V_STRING, V_SYMBOL, V_VECTOR};
union value_en { // this union takes a word in memory
   const void* vptr; // generic pointer, e.g. to free it
   enum value_kind_en* vkind; // the value of *vkind decides which member to use
   struct intvalue_st* vint;
   struct strvalue_st* vstr;
   struct symbvalue_st* vsymb;
   struct vectvalue_st* vvect;
};
typedef union value_en value_t;
#define NULL_VALUE  ((value_t){NULL})
struct intvalue_st {
  enum value_kind_en kind; // always V_INT for intvalue_st
  int num;
};
struct strvalue_st {
  enum value_kind_en kind; // always V_STRING for strvalue_st
  const char*str;
};
struct symbvalue_st {
  enum value_kind_en kind; // V_SYMBOL
  struct strvalue_st* symbname;
  value_t symbvalue;
};
struct vectvalue_st {
  enum value_kind_en kind; // V_VECTOR;
  unsigned veclength;
  value_t veccomp[]; // flexible array of veclength components.
};
```

To get the dynamic type of some value

```
enum value_kind_en value_type(value_t v) {
  if (v.vptr != NULL) return *(v.vkind);
  else return V_NONE;
}
```

Here is a "dynamic cast" to vectors:

```
struct vectvalue_st* dyncast_vector (value_t v) {
   if (value_type(v) == V_VECTOR) return v->vvect;
   else return NULL;
}
```

and a "safe accessor" inside vectors:

```
value_t vector_nth(value_t v, unsigned rk) {
   struct vectvalue_st* vecp = dyncast_vector(v);
   if (vecp && rk < vecp->veclength) return vecp->veccomp[rk];
   else return NULL_VALUE;
}
```

You'll typically define most of the short functions above as `static inline` in some header file.

BTW, if you can use [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) you are then able to code quite easily in some higher-level (but unsafe) style, and several Scheme interpreters are done that way. A variadic vector constructor could be

```
value_t make_vector(unsigned size, ... /*value_t arguments*/) {
   struct vectvalue_st* vec = GC_MALLOC(sizeof(*vec)+size*sizeof(value));
   vec->kind = V_VECTOR;
   va_args args;
   va_start (args, size);
   for (unsigned ix=0; ix<size; ix++) 
     vec->veccomp[ix] = va_arg(args,value_t);
   va_end (args);
   return (value_t){vec};
}
```

and if you have three variables

```
value_t v1 = somevalue(), v2 = otherval(), v3 = NULL_VALUE;
```

you could build a vector from them using `make_vector(3,v1,v2,v3)`

If you don't want to use Boehm's garbage collector (or design your own one) you should be very careful about defining destructors and documenting who, how, and when memory should be `free`-d; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785051/841108) example. So you could use `malloc` (but then test against its failure) instead of `GC_MALLOC` above but you need to carefully define and use some destructor function `void destroy_value(value_t)`

The strength of C is to be low-level enough to make code like above possible and define your own conventions (particular to your software).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want dynamic  typing in C. I was curious if this specific property of C is of any practical use.

Comment: But what exact property of C are you refering to? C  data structures are close to the metal, so have no hidden costs (except alignment and size constraints)

Comment: Exactly that :/

Comment: C was invented as a low-level language, but when optimizations are turned on compilers like gcc process a language which uses the low-level syntax but doesn't reliably provide low-level access to platform-provided behavioral guarantees.  One needs sizeof to use malloc and memcpy, but use for fancier address calculations may not be supported in "modern" C.